# Automatic MySQL data type casting

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

I just happened upon an interesting case of data type casting in MySQL.  Consider the following queries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 0 AS col) AS t WHERE t.col=123;   #Yields 0 rows
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 0 AS col) AS t WHERE t.col="123"; #Yields 0 rows
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 0 AS col) AS t WHERE t.col="0";   #Yields 1 row, col=0
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 0 AS col) AS t WHERE t.col="abc"; #Yields 1 row, col=0
```

Lines 1, 2, and 3 seem logical to me.  But on line 4, why, oh why, dear SQL, do you so eagerly cast `"abc"` to be equal to `0`?!

*I mean, I get it - `"abc"` isn't an integer, so `0` makes the most sense...  Is there a scenario in which this behavior is actually useful?  As far as I can tell, it likely just leads to bugs (as it did on our application)...*

Perhaps there's a MySQL "mode" that enables warnings for automatic type-casting like this?

Comment: I'm guessing that at the end of the day, the answer to this question will be, "It may not be ideal, but it's in the SQL spec... Deal with it!" :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that. This is not according to the ANSI SQL standard specification!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does implicit type casting for strings in a numeric context.  The leading numeric characters of the string are converted to a number, so a string such as `'abc'` gets converted to 0.

This can be very handy because this conversion does not cause an error (an explicit conversion would).

The moral is simple:  When comparing constants to columns, make the column the same type as the column.  That is, don't compare strings and numbers, lest something unexpected happen.

Comment: That's what I feared.  Maybe the best solution is to do some explicit type-casting in the scenarios in which this might occur in order to ensure nothing surprising happens?

Comment: @rinogo . . . The explicit casting mechanisms will return an error where this doesn't, so you have to be careful with `case` statements to get equivalent results.

Comment: BTW, did you mean "`cast` statements"?

Comment: @rinogo . . . Yes, that should have been `cast` in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely the way MySQL works.

When you use a comparison that compares a numeric object to a string constant, the string gets cast as an integer.  MySQL tries to interpret the string as an number, like this:

```
'0123abc' gets the value 123.
'1abc'    gets the value 1.
'abc'     gets the value 0.
```

What use is this? It comes in handy in `ORDER BY` clauses if you need numeric text strings ordered in numeric order with '112abc' after '12abc'.

Comment: Thank you for sharing a specific scenario in which this behavior is useful!